# Move last two or one row data if another section of data goes to next page in print format

Tags: html, css, printing, erpnext, frappe

[image]I have a html page for a print view. This page contain some data from back-end. There are a header section, item table section and signature section. Item table data comes dynamically that may have any number of items like 2,4,10,....50 possibly.
The problem is when signature section goes next page only then I should pass at least one Item of data (table row) to the next page.

Note: I am using only html css because it's a print format of ERPNext framework. I can't use Js or others.

How to do this.

Comment: add image of output , also add what code try,

Comment: picture added. I am trying page-break class. But won't work. The fact is it should be conditionally. Like when signature section goes next page as like as given picture then table row item at least one or two should go to next page as well.

Comment: add your code also

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be like this you need to `add more padding-top or margin-top` Or combine both in single parent div and you can try below css :

```
{page-break-inside: avoid;page-break-before:auto}
```

Please let me know if you find any issues

Comment: By adding this css inside page break avoided. But last row of the table not moved in the next page. When signature section goes to next page I should move at least one last row of the table in next page also